# Which package should I use to file a bug for the "application" menu?

Tags: 11.04, appmenu, bug-reporting, globalmenu

I am testing Natty and found an issue with the global menu, what is the proper package name to report the bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper name is "application menu" to distinguish it from the older (and [seperate project](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/)).

The modules are indicator-appmenu and appmenu-gtk. Unless it's indicator specific most bugs should be reported against appmenu-gtk.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-appmenu/
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/appmenu-gtk

[Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationMenu)